# Set language for comments in Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, spell-check, microsoft-office-2013

I have Polish version of Word in Office 2013, though I'm working mostly with English language documents. So far, when I was opening any document with language set to `English`, it was used for spell checking of both main document and all the comments.

Today I have received some international documents from India, with main document language set to `English`, but whenever I start writing new comment to any part of main text, it turns out, that comment's language is set to Polish. I would have to either change each new comment's language manually to `English`, rely on `Detect language automatically` option (which works with a great delay and language detection routines in Office 2013 aren't best) or make use of `Don't check spelling in this document` option. None of these solutions is actually available to me.

What am I missing? Is there any separate language setting for comments only? Or any option, that tells Word to use different language for spell checking of comments, than it uses for spell checking of main document text?

Comment: In the documents you have from India, how is the Linked style "COmment Text" defined? My guess is that it will have no language defined. If so, and assuming the style is based on the Normal style, how is Normal defined? If Normal does not specify a language, then I suspect that "Comment Text" will actually default to your installation language (i.e. Polish). It is worth comparing what you have in your own documents and in any templates that the documents are attached to.

Comment: My SAVIOR! :> Craft this comment as an answer and I'll be more than happy to accept it. Yes -- `Comment Text` style (`Text komentarza` in Polish version of Microsoft Office) had no language set. After setting it, everything now works like a charm! :>