# Microsoft Office Thinks the Words In My Review Comments Are Misspelled

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm running Microsoft Office 2013, and I just downloaded a document from a classmate.  My assignment is to review his paper.

After clicking on the "Review" tab and adding a comment, I find that almost every word in my comment is underlined red as if it is misspelled.

This is unusual because none of the words in the actual document are incorrectly identified as being misspelled.

The Review tab even has a "Language" section, which I clicked on and then found that my language was set to Spanish.  I changed the language to English.

But the words in the comments are still underlined red.  What's going on?  What could I be missing here?

Comment: Could be a situation similar to http://superuser.com/questions/1002166/set-language-for-comments-in-office-2013

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the language, make sure you select range of text where new language has to be applied. So typical and effective use is:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text.
2. Change the language in the same way as you described in your question.